# Inserting a JSON object into a blank database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have close to 120 JSON fields in objects.
A whole bunch of various versions of this  [sample JSON object](https://bpaste.net/show/a371d236c156)

I really don't have time to map every field, nor do I care if the field title is called Array 0 or some other default.

I just want the data stuffed into a database, maintaining it's structure in indexable format.

JSON is a perfectly valid data structure, why not use it?

I did find this ->  https://github.com/adamwulf/json-to-mysql  and hypothetically it would do the job.
But the software is broke (no error but nothing ever gets populated).

Other alternatives such as https://doctrine-couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/introduction.html  involve mapping. I don't have time to map 120 fields and nothing should require mapping, just use the existing.

Whats an easy way to stuff large JSON objects into MySQL, auto building the structure from an existing format?

Comment: Do you need each object field to become a field in the database, and if so, why? Are you querying for objects based on specific criteria?

Comment: @siliconwafer  yes!  {key => {key => value}}  becomes {field => link to sub key => field => element}

Comment: The 2nd answer here may solve your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616230/can-i-dynamically-create-a-mysql-table-from-json

Comment: I will be writing queries against the field names. Once 'whatever script' builds the structure, i'll just hunt threw the database looking for the data I need and run queries against the newly created field names.

Comment: @siliconwafer that's pretty much what I was thinking, though it is mysql_connect() and is going to take some tinkering to port it to PDO.  Let me give it a shot and see if I am successful. I think I follow how they are doing it. If successful, I will post the results as an edit.

Comment: iterate over fields to make a create table... doesn't seem like rocket science. then change the datatypes to whatever you need.

Comment: I'm sure you have good reasons to be using MySql, but to me this seems better suited for a MongoDB database. Then you can insert your JSON objects into whatever collection(ie. Table) you want without having to worry about creating it with the right structure.

Comment: @BeardFace you are probably right and this might be the experience to pushed me over the edge to MongoDB (I see the need), but right now I am looking for any cheat I can get because this task has had a few hiccups such as this. I honestly thought PhP had a default library to address 90% of this and switching to MongoDB this late in the game would not be a good thing..  Just headaches.   :(

Comment: I agree with BearFace mongo would be a lot better.

What you could do is iterate throug every object/property in the json file. Create the table with the right columns you need and then fill the database with the json data.

Comment: @SanderVisser  the deeper I look into Mongo, the more I acknowledge that.  It's still learning a new language. Doesn't look to bad. Gritting my teeth.